# Auto adjustment of table size automatically in ATLAS from QGIS

Tags: qgis, atlas

I would like to know if anyone knows any way to configure my ATLAS to automatically resize the attribute table if, for example, one field is having a long attribute than usual. I know in the layout of ArcGIS is possible but i am not finding the way in QGIS.

[image: Example]

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at the properties of the table and play around with the width for each column. I believe by default it is automatic, so it will adjust to the values it finds, but you can manually set each one to a set value. See the Main Properties section on this docs page: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_attribute_table.html

Comment: I was already playing around and testing it a lot without any success, I dont find any funcionality that automatically resize my table, and by default it doesnt do it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't a setting to set the width of the cell based on the length of the text, so instead I'd suggest a couple of options:

First - under the 'Position and Size' properties, set the reference point to the right-hand position - this way, if text does force the table to become wider, it won't bleed off the page:

[image]

Second - set the 'Oversized Text' option to 'wrap text', that way it will limit how much the table will widen if text is too big.

[image]